Why I'm getting (Execution failed for task ':gradle:compileGroovy') on every run on flutter?
I'm new in flutter and trying to develop my first project, every time i try to run my project i get the following message:
Launching lib\main.dart on sdk gphone x86 in debug mode...
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':gradle:compileGroovy'.


Could not resolve all files for configuration ':gradle:detachedConfiguration1'.
Could not find org.codehaus.groovy:groovy:?.?.??.

Does anyone has a clue about the cause? and thanks in advance
trying to develop a new flutter project

Does this answer your question? Execution Failed for task ':gradle:compileGroovy'

Please share the content to build.gradle and app/build.gradle files.

Thanks for your kind reply, I'm sorry i forgot to update this but someone has adviced me to use this version of gradle (gradle-7.4-all.zip) and It just worked fine, so the content of the build.gradle:
buildscript {
repositories {
google()
mavenCentral()
}
dependencies {
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.1.2' // Update version number accordingly
}
}
Gradle wrapper properties:
distributionUrl=https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.4-all.zip
However; I still wonder if there is a better gradle version to use, thanks
